# Could not import settings in zc.buildout

Tags: python, django, buildout

I just setup my project and I'm having a problem getting Django to work. Here's my `buildout.cfg`:

```
[buildout]
parts = python django
develop = .
eggs = myproject

[python]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
interpreter = python
eggs = ${buildout:eggs}

[django]
recipe = djangorecipe
project = myproject
settings = settings
wsgi = true
fcgi = true
```

I generated my Django project by running

```
$ bin/django startproject myproject src/
```

The settings file definitely exists and looks fine, but I get the following error:

> Error: Could not import settings 'myproject.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named myproject.settings

Any ideas as to what's going wrong?

Comment: can you show us the settings  file

Comment: turns out I was missing `eggs = ${buildout:eggs}` in the `[django]` section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't told your `[django]` part which eggs to use.

You normally have two or three parts in a buildout where you need the very same eggs. In your case the `[django]` and `[python]` part. Best practice is to add an `eggs` option to `[buildout]` (as you've done) and to use that in the other relevant parts as `eggs = ${buildout:eggs}`.

So... you're only missing that line in your `[django]` part.